# How to remove extended attribute "jquery123456" from element

Tags: javascript, expando

I have one element `"<a id="sample" jquery1234567="0">Testing</a>"`

I want to remove the last attribute (jquery1234567) from the above tag.
But the attribute "jquery1234567" will be generated dynamically.

Comment: That's used by jQuery internally. Why do you think you need to remove it?

Comment: To answer part of the "Why do you think you need to remove it?" question, this dynamically generated attribute prevents highlighting/selecting contents contained within the bounds of the element to which it is implemented in IE browsers. The question should be, "Why does JQuery need to implement it in IE?"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
  $("#sample").removeAttr('jquery1234567');
                (or)
  var id=1234567;
  $("#sample").removeAttr('jquery'+id);
```

this is not help for you..Pls add some extra description with code...

**Hi friend this will help you**

```
      lastAttrIndex=($("#sample")[0].attributes.length)-1;
      lastAttr=$("#sample")[0].attributes[lastAttrIndex].name;
      $("#sample").removeAttr(lastAttr);
```

Comment: we cannot find the exact attribute. that attribute will be dynamicly created , prefix with jquery

Comment: we cannot define var id=1234567; this will be dynamic content

Comment: What i exactly needed is to remove that particular attribute.Because it is dynamically generated in IE,but not in Firefox.

Comment: lastAttrIndex=($("#sample")[0].attributes.length)-1;
      lastAttr=$("#sample")[0].attributes[lastAttrIndex].name;
      $("#sample").removeAttr(lastAttr);

Answer (score 2):

The value of this generated attribute is `$.expando`. So if you want to remove it, simply use:

```
$('#sample').removeAttr($.expando);
```

Although I wouldn't recommend removing this attribute, because it is used by jQuery to keep track of the event handlers bound to DOM elements. The proper way to affect this behavior would be to unbind events from this element with jQuery.

Comment: This is the correct way, and as Romain comments, it isn't a good practice at all...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $.fn.getRegexAttr = function(regex, action) {

    if( !this.length ) return false;

    if( 'remove' == action ){

        var that = this;
        $(this[0].attributes)
            .filter(function(){ return regex.test(this.name); })
            .each(function(){ $(that).removeAttr(this.name); });


    }else if( 'fetch' == action ){

    return $(this[0].attributes)
            .filter(function(){ return regex.test(this.name); })
            .map(function(){ return $.trim(this.name); })
            .get();
    }
}
```

`if( $('#sample').getRegexAttr(/jquery[0-9]/, 'fetch') )
        alert( $('#sample').getRegexAttr(/jquery[0-9]/, 'fetch').join(',') );// To get the matched attributes`

`$('#sample').getRegexAttr(/jquery[0-9]/, 'remove');// To remove the matched attributes`

you can also verify in : http://jsfiddle.net/Nng8n/3/